# Wireless HD TV (Hide cords and hardware)

Tags: htpc, hdtv, high-definition

I am building a HTPC for my main entertainment system. The plan is to use Ceton for my HD DVR, and Windows Media Center to put it all together in one interface. The problem I am running into cords, cases and a clean presentation under the TV.

Is there a way to put your hardware (blue ray, HTPC, tuner, etc) in another room, then have the video output wirelessly to the TV? Either via network or antenna/dongle? And then have a wireless IR remote.

What is the best way to do this without sacrificing quality?

Thanks!
Tom

Comment: *"What is the best way to do this without sacrificing quality?"* - Wired, not wireless, connections for quality and reliability.

Comment: Thanks Sawdust, whats the best solution with the best quality I should say.

Comment: From what I have been reading it looks like a super long HDMI cable is what is going to do it.